# Prime number generation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I'm making a prime number scanning algorithm in Java. It uses the concept of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to efficiently find the prime numbers.

It works well and can calculate all the prime numbers under 1,000,000 in less than a second on my laptop, but I was wondering how the algorithm could be further improved.

```
public static void eratoImproved(long max){

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList<Long> invalidated = new ArrayList<>(); // where invalidated numbers will be stored.

    // prepare
    double maxFac = Math.sqrt(max);
    int f = 2;
    while(f <= maxFac){
        boolean isNew = true;
        for(long l : invalidated){
            if(f % l == 0){
                isNew = false;
            }
        }
        if(isNew) {
            invalidated.add(Math.round(f + 0.0));
        }
        f++;
    }

    ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    long i = 3; // current test

    for(long l : invalidated){
        primes.add(l);
    }

    while(i <= max){
        boolean v = true;
        for(long s : invalidated){
            if(i % s == 0){
                v = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(v){
            primes.add(i);
            long m = 2*i;
            if(primes.size() >= 150){
                String s = Math.round(((i + 0.0)/max)*100) + "%: ";
                for(long l : primes){
                    s += l + "/";
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                primes.clear();
            }

        }
        i += 2;
    }
    System.out.println("Completed search!");
    String s = "Remaining primes: ";
    for(long l : primes){
        s += l + "/";
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    primes.clear();

    System.out.println("Conducted search in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/1000 + " seconds.");
}
```

I've optimized everything I can think of, but I wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: For algorithm, you can use the concept of segmented sieve.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by janos is good, but is more about style. Here are some functional/performance observations related to your stated goal of efficiency.

- `invalidated.add(Math.round(f + 0.0))`, huh???
  `f` coerced to `double`, add a zero, call `round()`. Why?
  Suggest change `f` from `int` to `long`, and just use `invalidated.add(f)`.
- `while(f <= maxFac){` is done by continually coercing `f` to `double` and comparing the `double` values. Change `maxFac` to `long` using cast (truncation is ok here, no need for rounding).
- `for(long l : invalidated){ primes.add(l); }` is a long way of saying `primes.addAll(invalidated)`, except you're adding the overhead of unboxing and reboxing the values.
- You have two identical loops of `invalidated` to determine if prime. Move to reusable method ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).
- Never do `String += String` in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder`.
  And again, what's with the `i + 0.0`?

  ```
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
  buf.append(Math.round(i * 100.0 / max)).append("%: ");
  for (Long prime : primes)
      buf.append(prime).append('/');
  System.out.println(buf);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## Not a sieve

You claimed that you were using a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm but your program actually uses a trial division algorithm.  This trial division is fast enough for primes up to 1000000, but it becomes slower and slower as you try to find higher primes.

For instance, I modified your program to add up all the primes up to 50000000.  I compared it my own program that did the same thing using a sieve algorithm.  The trial division program took 13.4 seconds versus only 0.42 seconds for the sieve program, which is a 32x speed difference.

## Example of sieve

Here is the sieve function I used to add up all the primes to 50000000:

```
public static long addPrimes(int n)
{
    boolean [] isComposite = new boolean[n+1];
    int        sqrtn       = (int) Math.sqrt(n);

    // This is the sieve.  It computes whether each number is prime.
    for (int i = 3; i < sqrtn; i += 2) {
        if (!isComposite[i]) {
            int increment = i+i;
            for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j += increment) {
                isComposite[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now add up all the primes.
    long total = 0;

    // Start with 2 as the first prime.
    if (n >= 2)
        total = 2;

    // Add each prime from the sieve.
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2) {
        if (!isComposite[i]) {
            total += i;
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: You could probably get a small speed improvement, and certainly a memory usage improvement, by using `java.lang.BitSet` instead of `boolean[]`, tweaking the logic slightly so that each bit corresponds to an odd number, and using `nextClearBit`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor In fact I already did all that but I didn't want to confuse a beginner with too many advanced concepts.  The bit per odd number version was faster than the boolean version by about 70% for the primes up to 50000000.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, this seems fine.

In terms of coding practices, a couple of things can be improved.

#### Declare with interface type when it's enough

This list can be declared as a `List<Long>`:

> ```
> ArrayList<Long> invalidated = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Like this:

```
List<Long> invalidated = new ArrayList<>();
```

Apply this everywhere possible.

#### Use a `for` loop instead of `while` where more appropriate

Both `while` loops in your code can be rewritten as `for` loops, for example:

```
for (int f = 2; f <= maxFac; ++f) {
    boolean isNew = true;
    for (long l : invalidated) {
        if (f % l == 0) {
            isNew = false;
        }
    }
    if (isNew) {
        invalidated.add(Math.round(f + 0.0));
    }
}
```

Reasons to prefer this form:

- The key elements of the looping logic are all on one line, easy to see
- By declaring the loop variable in the `for` statement, you limit its scope to the loop body, making it impossible to misuse the variable outside the loop by mistake
- It's a common pattern for a counting loop

#### Poor names

The code is full of poor names. For example:

> ```
> for (long l : invalidated) {
>     primes.add(l);
> }
> ```

Why not name that loop variable `prime`? It would be all the more readable.

All the single-letter variables would be better to rename to something more descriptive to help reading the code.

#### Unnecessary statements

This variable is unused, so delete it:

> ```
> long m = 2 * i;
> ```

Comment: Thank you for helping me improve my practices-- this is a place where I feel that I really need to improve. I've implemented your suggestions, they can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/huxGWRWs)

Comment: I still see many single-letter variables there...

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hard to review this code because the documentation is extremely misleading.

> I'm making a prime number scanning algorithm in Java. It uses the
>   concept of the Sieve of Eratosthenes to efficiently find the prime
>   numbers.
>
> It works well and can calculate all the prime numbers under 1,000,000
>   in less than a second on my laptop, but I was wondering how the
>   algorithm could be further improved.

So you want to find primes. But actually it seems, from the way you use the `invalidated` list, that you *really* want to find primes between `sqrt(max)` and `max`. If that's the case,

1. Document it clearly, *especially* before asking other people to review the code!
2. Having computed `invalidated`, start `i` at `1 | (int)Math.sqrt(max)` to avoid repeating all of the calculation you've done to generate `invalidated`